# How to view Windows' equivalent of Unix Swap usage?

Tags: windows

How do I find out available and in-use virtual memory usage on Windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can view this information by opening up the `Resource Monitor` and selecting the `Memory` tab:

[image: Windows Resource Monitor]

"Used Physical Memory" is your RAM, while "Commit Charge" is the sum of RAM and the paging file, or the maximum available virtual memory. (This comes from a display of how much virtual memory windows has "committed" to being able to provide - the sum of every allocation request it has granted.)

Windows and Linux manage their paging/swap space differently, however. With Windows, a paging file with 0% utilization is not good for performance; rather, Windows will try to mirror every page from RAM onto the paging file if it can. This will allow it to quickly drop pages out of RAM when it needs to reuse them for something else. This is why Windows will try to create a paging file at least as big as the physical RAM you have installed on your machine. It's less of a swap file, and more of a backing store.

Comment: Thank you! So can I assume that commit charge - 2 * working set = swap usage of a process?

Comment: Having no swap is not good also on Linux. This part is being done pretty similarly in both OSes.

Comment: "Windows will try to mirror every page from RAM onto the paging file if it can" this can't be true, if it was, it would be non-stop writing data to disks. It doesn't. It only pushes pages that weren't used for long time into there, just like Linux does.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find out **available** and **in-use** virtual memory **usage** on
>   Windows?

At first, we need to invoke the [Performance Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435418/how-to-open-performance-options-dialog-from-command-line-or-system-call/2435452):

```
%windir%\system32\SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe
```

After selecting the `Advanced` tab, the frame `Virtual memory` reports the Total paging file size.

> Q1: **in-use** virtual memory

.
[image: Performance Options]

---

> Q2: **available** virtual memory

This is set / displayed by clicking on the `Change...` button (see above)

---

> Q3: virtual memory **usage**

About this last question, the resource monitor might help now.

```
%windir%\system32\resmon.exe
```

Here, the `Hard Faults/sec` parameter shows the expected info (column values and graph)

[image: Resource Monitor Graphs]

*When should I buy more RAM memory for this machine… is another story.

Or not.*
:)

Answer (score 1):

**THE ANSWER**

Note: These are the exact steps for Win 7. I think is the same on Win 8.

To get the actual amount of PageFile usage, start 'Performance Monitor' (perfmon.exe), and 'Add Counters' -> 'Paging File' -> 'Usage'.

It will give you the answer in %, but you know the total amount of paging file so you can calculate the exact amount of USED paging file (in MB).

**To read the total amount of paging file:**
Press Win+Break to open 'System properties'. Go to: 'Advanced' -> 'Performance' -> 'Advanced' -> 'Virtual memory' -> 'Total paging file size' (in MB) ).

Answer (score -4):

This is easily found in the Windows Task Manager under the *Performance* tab.